# Mitaka nova-manage api_db sync 'error: No sql_connection parameter is established'

Tags: openstack-nova

I am trying to set up a Mitaka OpenStack cloud.  But when I try to execute:

```
# /usr/bin/nova-manage --debug api_db sync
```

And the I get the error message:

```
error: No sql_connection parameter is established
```

Yet I am able to access the nova database via `mysql` command line, using the values I am using for my I have in the /etc/nova/nova.conf:

```
[database]
connection=mysql://nova:nova@svl-os:3306/nova
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Mitaka release they added a new DB schema, nova_api.  So I needed to add ...

```
[api_database]
connection=mysql://nova_api_db_user:password@mydbhost:3306/nova_api
```

... to my /etc/nova/nova.conf file.